# How to capture a Genie?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, magic

I seem to remember there being a way that a character could capture Outsiders and seal these creatures away in small items, in order to create the stereotypical "Genie captured in an object" trope. However, the details of the process currently elude me.

Planar binding seemed like a good way to go, but as far as I can see it only traps such a creature within a particular space- Not in an object.
So, if I would want to, for example, capture a genie inside a gemstone, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***binding***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#binding) [conj] (*Player's Handbook* 204–5) has six different ways in which it can be cast. Each way confines the victim somehow, but on Minimus Containment, in part, says, "The subject is shrunk to a height of 1 inch or even less and held within some gem, jar, or similar object. The binding is permanent. The subject does not need to breathe, eat, or drink while contained, nor does it age."

The target of a *binding* spell can be any living creature including an outsider. I suspect the name of the spell *binding* was similar enough to the name of the spell [*planar binding*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#planar-binding) that it might've caused one's memory to misremember that the *binding* spell only affected outsiders.

Comment: @Miniman I kind of didn't want to mislead any readers: Not only did the question seem like it wanted the spell, an [*efreeti bottle*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#efreeti-bottle) is 145,000 gp crap shoot that holds but can't capture another genie, and an [*iron flask*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#iron-flask) is a 170,000 gp crap shoot that may or may not be full, but still can only rarely capture a new creature within it. (The creature need only succeed on a DC 19 Will save to avoid its effects.)

Comment: Fair enough! And yeah, this is definitely the answer the question was looking for (gem rather than bottle).